# Tensorflow log-likelihood for two probability vectors which might contain zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow, log-likelihood

Suppose I have two tensors,  `p1` and `p2` in tensorflow of the same shape which contain probilities, some of which might be zero or one. Is their and elegant way of calculating the log-likelihood pointwise: `p1*log(p2) + (1-p1)*log(1-p2)`?

Implementing it naively using the tensorflow functions

```
p1*tf.log(p2) + (1-p1)*tf.log(1-p2)
```

risks calling `0*tf.log(0)` which will give a `nan`.

Answer (score 1):

As an initial hack (there most be a better solution) I add an epsilon inside the `log`:

```
eps = 1e-10
p1*tf.log(p2+eps) + (1-p1)*tf.log(1-p2+eps)
```

which prevents a `log(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [CRF](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/crf). It contains implementation of Log Likelihood. In particular you can take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py#L128)

Comment: Thank you, however it is very difficult to see figure out what is what in this code. I would expect it to be possible to do using less then 5 lines of tensorflow code.

Comment: If you remove all documentary comments and input parameters validation you will get the code that is roughly 10 lines long.